# Coq for HoTT: proving || P-> X || -> (P-> ||X||)

Tags: coq, truncation, homotopy-type-theory

I need to prove in Coq that for any type X and any proposition P (though I think it should work even if P is a type) there exists

trunc_impl: || P-> X || -> (P-> ||X||)

where ||_|| is the symbol used in HoTT book to indicate propositional truncation.

I demonstrated the statement in type theory: one gets the thesis by using the induction principle of propositional truncation, assuming from an H : || P-> X || and a p: P that H=|H'|, with H': P->X , and then defines trunc_impl(p):= |H'(p)|.
(|-| indicates the constructor for the trucation, i.e. |_| : A -> ||A||).

By the way, I cannot write it in Coq!
Any help would be very appreciated.

I am using the HoTT library available on GitHub.

Comment: Are you asking where to find propositional truncation in the HoTT library? In that case, you will need to `Require Import Truncations.` in your file. Truncations in general are `Tr`, but if you want propositional truncation use `merely`. Then the statement you want to prove would be `Definition trunc_impl {X P : Type} : merely (P -> X) -> P -> merely X.`.

Comment: By the way, if you are still having trouble feel free to open an issue on github. You are also welcome to join the Zulip chat: https://hott.zulipchat.com/join/ry13tfnvchmbo2u56f7jl4w9/

Comment: Actually with that definition I get the error:
*The term "merely (P -> X)" has type "Trunc.TruncType (Overture.trunc_S Overture.minus_two)" which should be Set, Prop or Type*.
\\

By the way, my question was about the tactics to use to prove the statement, in particular how to use the recursion principle for prop truncation. Also, thanks for the link to the Zulip chat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Require Import Basics.` since coq doesn't know Trunc.TruncType can be coerced to Type otherwise. The tactics that you want to be aware of are `apply Trunc_ind` which will act on a goal like `forall (x : Tr _ _), _`.

`intros x y` and `revert x` will come in handy to get the goal into a form you want to apply `trunc_ind` to .

You also have the (custom) tactic `strip_truncations` which will search the context for any terms that are wrapped up with a truncation and try to do induction on them to remove them. This requires the goal to be as truncated but that shouldn't be a problem here.

Finally, the constructor for truncations is `tr`, so you can use `apply` there.